# Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'popover'?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I use table cell object as the trigger of twitter bootstrap popover, it returned me with this error.

```
Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'popover'
```

However, if i use buttons or `<a>` tag, it works perfectly.

Is it possible at all to use `<td>` as trigger at all?

Thanks!

```
$('.fc-omg').popover({title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover', content: "It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!"});
```

when class is defined in `<input>` tag, it works, however, it does not work when it is defined inside `td` tag.

Comment: `popover()` is not a native method of a HTML element. Did you forget surrounding it by `$(` and `)`: `$("#mycell").popover()`?

Comment: @ComFreek I have the correct syntax. it works when class name is defined in side input tag, but not td tag.

Comment: @user2363192 No, [HTMLTableCellElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) is the element that is in the DOM (aka the 'thing' you get when doing `document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0]` or `$('td')[0]`, not a jQuery element. The line of code you have in your question works fine in the quick test I made, so there must be a problem with how you select the element(s) you want the popover to display.